# Semi Eclipse CSS in RN

Tags: react-native

I am trying to get this shape using css but i am not even close to achieving one.

I have tried to use a parent view to make a rectangle and then a semi eclipse, but it does not look even close to the result i want. Also my solution is not scaling to different devices and orientation.

Desired Image: [Desired Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcEg2.png)

My Solution: [MY Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyogK.png)

My Code:

```js
  renderAvtarImage () {
    return (
      <FastImage
        style={styles.avatar}
        source={{
          uri: 'https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar6.png'
        }}
      />
    )
  }
 
 <View style={styles.RectangleShapeView} />
        <TouchableHighlight
          style={{
              top: -110,
            borderRadius:
              Math.round(
                Dimensions.get('window').width + Dimensions.get('window').height
              ) / 2,
            width: '100%',
            height: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.5,
            backgroundColor: '#f00',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center'
          }}
          underlayColor='#ccc'
          onPress={() => alert('Yaay!')}
        >
          <Text>{} </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <View style={styles.content}>
          <View>
            {/* <FastImage
              style={styles.tmdbLogo}
              source={require('../../assets/img/tmdb.png')}
              resizeMode='contain'
            /> */}
            {this.renderAvtarImage()}
          </View>
```

```css
 avatar: {
    width: 130,
    height: 130,
    borderRadius: 63,
    borderWidth: 4,
    borderColor: 'white',
    marginBottom: 10,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginTop: 30
  },
   RectangleShapeView: {
    width: '100%',
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#F00'
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

add below attributes to touchable opacity:

```
<TouchableHighlight
          style={{
            top: -200,
            borderRadius: Math.round(
                Dimensions.get('window').width + Dimensions.get('window').height
              ) / 2,
            width: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.8,
            height: 300,
            backgroundColor: '#f00',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            transform: [
              { scaleX: 2 }
            ]
          }}
          underlayColor='#ccc'
          onPress={() => alert('Yaay!')}
        >
          <Text>{} </Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
```

output:

[image]

Hope this works...